# EKS: kubectl exec does not respect streamingConnectionIdleTimeout

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubectl

Using EKS with Kubernetes 1.21, managed nodegroups in a private subnet. I'm trying to set the cluster up so that `kubectl exec` times out after inactivity regardless of the workload being `exec`ed into, and without any client configuration.

I'm aware of https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/5563, except we're on 1.21 with Docker runtime, not containerd yet.

I set `streamingConnectionIdleTimeout: 3600s` on the kubelet in the launch template:

```bash
cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json | jq '.streamingConnectionIdleTimeout = "3600s"' > /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json

/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh {{CLUSTER_NAME}}
```

And confirmed with `curl -sSL "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/(node name)/proxy/configz"`.

However, `kubectl exec` still does not time out.

I confirmed `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time = 7200` on both the client and the node, so we should be hitting the streaming connection idle timeout before Linux starts sending keepalive probes.

Reading through [How `kubectl exec` Works](https://erkanerol.github.io/post/how-kubectl-exec-works/), it seems possible that the EKS managed control plane is keeping the connection alive. There are people online who have the *opposite* problem - their connection times out regardless of `streamingConnectionIdleTimeout` - and they solve it by adjusting the timeout on the load balancer in front of their k8s API server. However, there are no knobs (that I know of) to tweak in that regard on the EKS managed control plane.

I would appreciate any input on this topic.